# magento 2 website not working after deployment from nginx to apache2

Tags: php, nginx, apache2, magento2, php-7.1

My website is work fine here [development site](http://novastore.aaartise.com/)

which is on **nginx server php version 7.1**

But when i deployed here [production site](http://www.novastore.sg/)
 it gives me error like **add to cart functionality, unnecessary index.php link** on url (note production site uses **apache2 server with php version 7.1**).

what I did was while moving to production I made changes as follows  :-

1. changed database setting from app/etc/env.php
2. in database changed unsecure and secure URL's from
   "soft_core_config_data" table
3. did following changes in "soft_core_config_data" table

   a. Search - dev/static/sign to 0 *(number zero)*

   To make admin accessible

   b. Search - web/seo/use_rewrites - 0 in *(number zero)*

Added command to the root folder of the project :-

1. sudo chmod -R 777
2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

4 .php bin/magento cache:flush

5 .php bin/magento cache:clean

6 .rm -rf var/cache var/view_preprocessed var/page_cache
generated/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcmath package was missing in PHP extension.  Now add to cart is working